# msdn example ExtractMetaData

Tags: c#, call

[MSDN ExtractMetaData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Trying to get back up to speed.  So sorry if this is an overly simply question.

I have created the `PictureViewer` example from MSDN and am trying to add some additional capability.  Specifically, I am trying to read and display specific MetaData from an image file.

In trying to understand the example it seems that I need to link a form control to call the example code.  But I am failing to understand what the call should look like.  placing

```
ExtractMetadata(e); in an event handler giving me a error
```

> Argurment 1: cannot convert from 'System.EventArgs' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs'

am I missing a '`this`' pointer or something?

///////////////////
I guess I needed more information.  If you look at the LINK at the top of the comment ExtractMetadata is a call to GET EXIF data (Exchangable Image File) from the image file but it requires PaintEventArgs e, which is a parameter of the Paint Event handler so it requires the System.Drawing.Imaging namespace.

Here is the code that the example provides and I am attempting to execute:

```
    private void ExtractMetaData(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create an Image object. 
            Image theImage = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\DadPC\\Desktop\\testrunfiles\\fakePhoto.jpg");

            // Get the PropertyItems property from image.
            PropertyItem[] propItems = theImage.PropertyItems;

            // Set up the display.
            Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10);
            SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            int X = 0;
            int Y = 0;

            // For each PropertyItem in the array, display the id, 
            // type, and length.
            int count = 0;
            foreach (PropertyItem propItem in propItems)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Property Item " +
                    count.ToString(), font1, blackBrush, X, Y);
                Y += font1.Height;

                e.Graphics.DrawString("   ID: 0x" +
                    propItem.Id.ToString("x"), font1, blackBrush, X, Y);
                Y += font1.Height;

                e.Graphics.DrawString("   type: " +
                    propItem.Type.ToString(), font1, blackBrush, X, Y);
                Y += font1.Height;

                e.Graphics.DrawString("   length: " +
                    propItem.Len.ToString() +
                    " bytes", font1, blackBrush, X, Y);
                Y += font1.Height;
                count += 1;
            }
            font1.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error." +
                "Make sure the path to the image file is valid.");
        }
    }
```

And in my forms app I have been trying to figure out how to call the function

```
    private void metadataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExtractMetaData(e);
    }
```

But that is where I have been unsuccessful in figuring out what it expects me to pass including try nothing ExtractMetaData();

Long term I want to read and right specific metadata to the image files but I was using this example for MSDN to get started.

[Link to Metadata reference table](http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html)

Comment: Could you show handler from which you call `ExtractMetadata`?

Answer (score 0):

This code is meant to be called from a Paint event handler. It uses the Graphics object that is available at that time to draw directly onto the display.  Something like this:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   ExtractMetadata(e);
}
```

The event handler is normally added in the Visual Studio Designer. But it will add this line to the Designer.cs file:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ...
    this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
   ...
}
```

You can also add this line of code manually in the constructor (after the call to InitializeComponent)